# Flex wrap only work when i make a uncheck and check in inspect element

Tags: css

I think I am the only one who is facing the problem.
I have tried updating my chrome browser and also tried in some another browsers,
But every where same problem.
The `flex-warp:wrap` only works when I go to inspect element and toggle the check button of the `flex-wrap` property, as soon as I reload the browser it not working again

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own, tell what you've tried to achieve the goal and add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question if possible, at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap only work if your items overflow the container (flexbox). Make sure

Comment: Now it work when i give the property ```overflow:hidden;``` but I need that flexbox scrollable, is there any way

Comment: Are you trying set width or height for parent element ? If you want scroll you must set height for your parent element and use `overflow-y:scroll` property